# 'Speak' command does not work

Tags: sound

I have Mathematica 12.1.0.0. When I execute the command

> Speak["Hello"]

I hear nothing. In the earlier versions of the software, Mathematica would 'speak' the words/string inside the 'Speak' function. How to fix it? My computer audio system works fine.

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 focal (x86-64) (Linux Kernel: 5.4.0-53-generic)

Comment: It works on my system `$Version="12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"`.

Comment: Works fine for me on "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Comment: Can you `sudo apt-get install espeak` and see if `espeak` works as intended?  If it does not, then that suggests there's a problem with your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: You don't say...

Comment: @bobthechemist It does not work even after doing sudo apt-get install espeak

Comment: Does `espeak "hello"` work from the command line (outside of mathematica?

Comment: @bobthechemist Yes, it does.

Comment: I'm working from an RPi distro here, but the version of espeak that Mathematica uses is in "/opt/Wolfram/WolramEngine/12.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-ARM"  The next step might be to see if that version of espeak is also working on your system.

Comment: Sound[{SoundNote["C"], SoundNote["G"]}] works?

Comment: @Syed Yes, it does.

Comment: @Sashwat Tanay : Try this if you haven't already: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioPlay.html

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioChannelAssignment.html and try reassigning the channel. See if changes something.

Comment: Works fine on Fedora with espeak. ReadList["!espeak -s 160 -a 100 'Works fine on Fedora with espeak'&"] Even has different languages: ReadList["!espeak -s 160 -a 100 -vde 'Tritt Windows in die Tonne und lern endlich Linux'&"]

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for Speak, it uses your computer's OS to generate the sound. There doesn't appear to be any issues with the command or Mathematica, so it is likely an issue with your OS. If you recently updated, it could be a bug in your OS version. If you don't have the most recent updates, you could try updating your computer to see if that fixes your OS issue.